# Add an attribute to every item in a DynamoDB table with millions of items

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am pretty new to AWS, but I need to add an attribute (and set the value to something) to every single item in a DynamoDB table.

I'm trying to write a generic script that will be able to do this to any table passed into it.

After a little bit of digging, it looks like I should be able to do this just by doing a scan of the table, getting the items, and then updating every single item.

My questions are:
(1) Does this seem like a reasonable approach?
(2) Is there an easier / better way to do this automatically? (a table-wide addition of an attribute to every item in the table?)

Comment: there is no easier approach, however the given approach will also have issues, like what if application is also trying to write to the table? Another thing that you can do is instead of readily updating all the items update the items as and when they are requested.

Comment: Would you happen to know what the default behavior is if another application is trying to write to the table at the same time the scan and update is happening? 

Will the one that gets to the item first succeed, but then the second one trying to do the update will fail?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.ReadConsistency

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes it sounds reasonable, not ideal, but reasonable
2. Sure, there is always a better way, but this is an easy way, Here is a snippet I ran as a local JS file...

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    region:'us-east-1'
});

async function main(event, context) {
    let tableContents;
    try{
        //get items from dynamo
        const params = {
            TableName: `${YOUR_TABLE_NAME}`,
        };
        tableContents = await scanDB(params);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
    let calls = [];
    tableContents.forEach(function(value){
        let params = {
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":newAttribute": false,
            },
            Key: {
                "indexKey": value.indexKey
            },
            TableName: `${YOUR_TABLE_NAME}`,
            UpdateExpression: "SET newAttribute = :newAttribute",
            };
        calls.push(dynamoDb.update(params).promise());
    });
    let response;
    try{
        response = await Promise.all(calls);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    return response;
}
async function scanDB(params) {
    let dynamoContents = [];
    let items;
    do{
        items =  await dynamoDb.scan(params).promise();
        items.Items.forEach((item) => dynamoContents.push(item));
        params.ExclusiveStartKey  = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    }while(typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined");
    return dynamoContents;
};
main();
```

Good luck!

Comment: You might need to add the sort key to the expression, if you have a composite key.

Answer (score 0):

With the solution of @geauser @rocketlobster

with millions of records to edit, didn't you face to write throttling issues ?

On my side, we had to chunk the scan to mitigate the updates

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    region:'us-east-1'
});

const _chunk = require("lodash/chunk");

async function main(event, context) {
    let tableContents;
    try{
        //get items from dynamo
        const params = {
            TableName: `${YOUR_TABLE_NAME}`,
        };
        tableContents = await scanDB(params);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
    
    const MAX_CONCURRENT = 10; // example
    const chunks = _chunk(tableContents, MAX_CONCURRENT);

    for (const chunk of chunks) {
      const promiseQueue = [];

      for (const itemRecord of chunk) {
        let params = {
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":newAttribute": false,
          },
          Key: {
              "indexKey": itemRecord.indexKey
          },
          TableName: `${YOUR_TABLE_NAME}`,
          UpdateExpression: "SET newAttribute = :newAttribute",
        };
        promiseQueue.push(dynamoDb.update(params).promise());
      }

      const responses = await Promise.allSettled(promiseQueue);
      const fulfilled = responses.filter(
        (output) => output.status === "fulfilled"
      );
      const rejects = responses.filter(
        (output) => output.status === "rejected"
      );
  
      errors.push(...rejects);
    }
    console.log(`Nb errors : ${errors.length}`, errors);
}
async function scanDB(params) {
    let dynamoContents = [];
    let items;
    do{
        items =  await dynamoDb.scan(params).promise();
        items.Items.forEach((item) => dynamoContents.push(item));
        params.ExclusiveStartKey  = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    }while(typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined");
    return dynamoContents;
};
main();
```

Also, you can instead add some rate limiting :

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Initialize DynamoDB client
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ region: 'your-region' });

// Specify your table name
const tableName = 'your-table-name';

// Specify the attribute to be updated
const newAttributeName = 'new_attribute';
const newAttributeValue = 'new_value';

// Specify the rate limit and sleep time between updates (in milliseconds)
const rateLimit = 1000;  // 1 update per second

// Function to update a single record
const updateRecord = async (primaryKeyValue) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Key: { 'yourPrimaryKey': primaryKeyValue },
    UpdateExpression: `SET ${newAttributeName} = :value`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value': newAttributeValue },
  };

  try {
    await dynamodb.update(params).promise();
    console.log(`Record updated for primary key: ${primaryKeyValue}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error updating record for primary key ${primaryKeyValue}: ${error.message}`);
  }
};

// Function to scan and update records with rate limiting
const scanAndUpdateRecords = async () => {
  const scanParams = { TableName: tableName };
  
  try {
    const scanResult = await dynamodb.scan(scanParams).promise();
    const items = scanResult.Items;

    for (const item of items) {
      const primaryKeyValue = item.yourPrimaryKey;  // Change 'yourPrimaryKey' to the actual primary key attribute name

      // Update the record
      await updateRecord(primaryKeyValue);

      // Rate limiting to avoid exceeding provisioned capacity
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, rateLimit));
    }

    // Continue scanning if there are more items
    if (scanResult.LastEvaluatedKey) {
      scanAndUpdateRecords();
    } else {
      console.log('Update process completed.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error scanning and updating records: ${error.message}`);
  }
};

// Start the script
scanAndUpdateRecords()
```